# Django user input steps needed

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I'm a noob I know.
So I want to build a web app that allows the user to enter text. Then have the web server send an email based on the text with a message from another file.

What would be the optimal way to accomplish this? I am new to Django but have experience with Python. If someone could give me a basic bullet point way on how to do this I can google the rest. I just don't know where to start.

Comment: This should be your starting point https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/  for sending mail

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of good guides online. The django documentation will take you step by step through making your first django app.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

Django has a sendmail library that you can use once you get your app started

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/

Answer (score 1):

This guide is help you to go step by step

Tango with Django : http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/

Or

http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/index.html

as well you have to follow official documentation.because Tango with Django may cause version issues but Django girls tutorial seems updated.

Official : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/